# How to draw Google Line Charts when some of the values are missing?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I've found the following JavaScript code on [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagelinechart.html):

```
  function drawVisualization() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addRows(4);
    data.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
    data.setValue(0, 2, 400);
    data.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 1170); // sales for 2005
    data.setValue(1, 2, 460);
    data.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 860);
    data.setValue(2, 2, 580);
    data.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 1030);
    data.setValue(3, 2, 540);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ImageLineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 500, height: 250, min: 0});
  }
```

If I comment out the line of code setting the value for the 2005 sales, the *Sales* line will appear on the graph starting from 2006 and ending in 2007. I was expecting to see the *Sales* line from 2004 (at Y=1000) to 2006 (at Y=860) and from 2006 (at Y=860) to 2007 (at Y=1030).

How do I draw that chart if I don't have the value for the 2005 sales, but I have the values for 2004, 2006 and 2007?

**Actual result:**

[image: actual chart]

**Expected result:** (I added the value 930 for the 2005 sales only to show what I want to accomplish; I hope there's a better way of doing this without computing all the missing Y values for all the series)

[image: expected chart]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If it's possible for you to use the javascript version of this chart, then you can achieve something like what you want by using the interpolateNulls option available through the [line chart options](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html#Configuration_Options).

Here's a working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart', 'imagelinechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addRows(4);
        data.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 400);
        data.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
        //data.setValue(1, 1, 1170); // sales for 2005
        data.setValue(1, 2, 460);
        data.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
        data.setValue(2, 1, 860);
        data.setValue(2, 2, 580);
        data.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
        data.setValue(3, 1, 1030);
        data.setValue(3, 2, 540);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 500, height: 250, min: 0, interpolateNulls: true});
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked great, saved my lots of time. Thanks

Comment: If I have only one value, is it possible to show single point only? I have tried this. but not working.