# Draw Google Line Chart with multiple missing values

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I copied this code from Google Line Chart reference and made some small changes:

```
function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dag');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Målvikt');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Uppmätt vikt');


    data.addRows([
      [1, 37.8, 55.0],
      [2, null, 69.5],
      [3, null, 57],
      [4, null, 18.8],
      [5, null, 17.6],
      [6, null, 13.6],
      [7, null, 12.3],
      [8, null, 29.2],
      [9, null, 42.9],
      [10, null, 30.9],
      [11, null, 7.9],
      [12, null, 8.4],
      [13, null, 6.3],
      [14, 30.8, 6.2]
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
            subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)',
            interpolateNulls: true
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

My first line is not generated at all.
As you see, I want to just give the first and last value for the curve named "Målvikt" and draw a straight line between them. I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859298/how-to-draw-google-line-charts-when-some-of-the-values-are-missing) and added `interpolateNulls: true`  but actually it did not solve my problem.
I then changed all nulls except one to some value, but there still was no line between its neighbors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that `google.charts.Line` component does not support `interpolateNulls` option.

Secondly, there is typo in specifying `interpolateNulls` option.

Since `interpolateNulls` property does not belong to `chart` property according to [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?csw=1#Configuration_Options), the line:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        interpolateNulls: true
    }
};
```

should be replaced with:

```
var options = {
    interpolateNulls: true
};
```

Having said that, i would recommend to utilize `google.visualization.LineChart` from `corechart` package instead of `google.charts.Line` component from `line` package. In that case `interpolateNulls` option could applied as demonstrated below:

**Working example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dag');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Målvikt');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Uppmätt vikt');


    data.addRows([
     [1, 37.8, 55.0],
     [2, null, 69.5],
     [3, null, 57],
     [4, null, 18.8],
     [5, null, 17.6],
     [6, null, 13.6],
     [7, null, 12.3],
     [8, null, 29.2],
     [9, null, 42.9],
     [10, null, 30.9],
     [11, null, 7.9],
     [12, null, 8.4],
     [13, null, 6.3],
     [14, 30.8, 6.2]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
        subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)',
        interpolateNulls: true,
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };

    //var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));


    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="linechart_material" style="width: 640px; height: 480px"></div>
```